# dist-upgrade from within a proxy - implications

Tags: apt, proxy, dist-upgrade

What are the implications of running

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

from within a proxy?

**Edit**

I have 2 concerns

- A caching-proxy server may mess up my apt cache.
- The proxy server itself might be upgraded which may cause an issue.

Comment: Umm... You'll upgrade your proxy server — could you clarify what you're concerned about? That `apt-get` won't be able to reach the repositories because it's running on the proxy server?

Comment: Your question lacks clarity. Do you mean running a dist-upgrade on the OS of the proxy server, which would be 'within' it? Or do you mean that the network the machine(s) being dist-upgraded run through a proxy server? Or do you mean that you are using something like apt-proxy to cache the dist-upgrade? Edit your question until it contains an actual question, use more words, until you are clear to other readers.

Comment: Make an effort to resist the urge to be excessively terse, there is no benefit. What is the proxy server, be specific, don't be so vague as if you are afraid to ask the actual question. Enter all relevant technical information, otherwise there's no point in posting a technical question in the first place.

Comment: @StephenKitt : Please see the update..

Answer (score 2):

For other readers, this is how to NOT ask a question, that is, do not list any relevant data about the OS of the machines using the caching server, do not list the OS of the caching server, do not list the caching technology being used, then expect an answer. Then resist the requests to actually post meaningful information when asked to fill out your question by typing as little as humanly possible in response.

In answer to your exceedingly terse question:

1. The caching server of course will not be upgraded if it is caching the packages being requested by machines configured to use that proxy server. The packages will be inert on the proxy server, they are files, nothing more.
2. debian packages have file names that reflect their specific version numbers, when a file is requested from the caching server, assuming the caching server is properly configured, if that data is current, it will result in the right package version being downloaded. For example, if the package is nano, the current stretch file name for the amd64 deb file is: nano_2.6.3-1_amd64.deb.
3. I am not sure about the actual update data itself, what you get when you download version information via apt-get update. This is heavily dependent on the configuration of the server.
4. It's unclear if you are using something like apt-cacher, which is specifically designed to cache apt data, or if it's a generic caching server, so no answer can be given there.
5. If you were using something like apt-cacher or approx, these things 'just work' out of the box, after setup, they 'know' how to handle apt-get update requests, and know how to cache the packages. Well, barring bugs and other issues, of course.
6. the OS of the proxy server itself will be upgraded however it's been told to upgrade, the various machines accessing it have nothing to do with that, nor do the packages they request and which it caches have anything to do with the upgrade of the proxy server itself, unless the proxy server itself is one of the machines using the cache, which you can do, but then that just comes down to how you have the upgrades of the proxy server configured.

As an aside, an improperly configured proxy/caching server will start getting bloated with old out of date packages over time, which is worth keeping in mind, as newer versions replace the old ones.